# Why does regex return one digit?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get last digits from strings.

For example: "Text11" - `11`; "Te1xt32" - `32` and etc.

I write this regex:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^(.+)(?<Number>(\d+))(\z)");
```

And use it:

```
 regex.Match(input).Groups["Number"].Value;
```

That returns `1` for "Text11" and `2` for "Te1xt32" instead `11` and `32`.

So question, Why `\d+` get only last digit?

Comment: You should use this regex in RightToLeft mode, which should make it slightly more efficient, and it should return what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `.+` at the first is greedy by default, so `.+` matches greedily upto the last and then it backtracks to the previous character and uses the pattern `\d+` inorder to produce a match. You need to add a non-greedy quantifier `?` next to the `+` to make the regex engine to do  a non-greedy match or shortest possible match.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^(.+?)(?<Number>(\d+))(\z)");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wH1nK1/7)

Comment: you could remove the unwanted capturing grous. like `@"^(.+?)(?<Number>\d+)\z"`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use the same regex with in [`RightToLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#RightToLeft) mode:

```
var input = "Te1xt32";
// I removed some unnecessary capturing groups in your regex
var regex = new Regex(@"^(.+)(?<Number>\d+)\z", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

// You need to specify the starting index as the end of the string
Match m = regex.Match(input, input.Length);

Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["Number"].Value);
```

[**Demo on ideone**](http://ideone.com/eP4sVa)

Since what you want to find is at the end of the string and the part in front doesn't have any pattern, going from right to left avoids some backtracking in this case, though the difference, if any, is going to be insignificant in this case.

`RightToLeft` mode, as the name suggests, performs the match from right to left, so the numbers at the end of the string will be greedily consumed by `\d+` before the rest is consumed by `.+`.

Comment: Thanks @ndahtdh. I found easier solution: "(?<Number>\d+)\z". Just it was interesting, Why I get that result.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<Number>\d+)\z");
```

Comment: Yep. In the end I did so. But I wondered why my expression was obtained such a result.